# If-command in Stata 11

Tags: if-statement, stata

The variable variable_1 ranges from 0 to 10 plus a 99 for missing values. I want to do a stata calculation using only the values from 0 to 10 but the if command doesn't seem to work. The sum command result states 99 as the max value. How can I select all the values that are not 99?

```
if variable_1 !=99 {
        sum variable_1
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to use an if qualifier, not an if statement. That is append your if statement rather than writing it before your calculation.

```
sum variable_1 if variable_1 != 99
```

http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/multiple-operations/

Comment: @frankunfrei: -1: What is the difference between my answer and your answer?

Comment: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/ is a more direct source.

Comment: @Metrics: Sorry, I didn't actually see your answer. I think the slide up window that appears when you add an answer blocked your answer as it was so short. You could maybe mention if qualifiers and if statements and maybe Nick Cox link for clarification. I would then delete my answer. That OK with you?

Comment: @Metrics frankundfrei actually explained his answer's reasoning, and many people often find that to be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum variable_1 if variable_1 !=99
```